# Have a ComboBox not "use" the F4 key

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I have an application where the user wants F4 to be the "Process Orders" button.  (There is a long history around that key performing this feature.)

Today I found out that if the focus is in a ComboBox then F4 makes the ComboBox perform a dropdown.

**Is there a way to make that not happen?**

*Update:* I tried this using Delphi and it happens there too. While I am still curious, this seems to be a "baked in" Windows thing.  I am going to ask the users to pick another shortcut.

Comment: subscribe to the event and abort it, or reverse the result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to the answers above, here is a reusable solution without the need to create a custom control:

```
public static class ComboBoxHelper
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty DisableF4HotKeyProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("DisableF4HotKey", typeof(bool),
            typeof(ComboBoxHelper), new PropertyMetadata(false, OnDisableF4HotKeyChanged));

    public static bool GetDisableF4HotKey(DependencyObject obj)
    {
        return (bool)obj.GetValue(DisableF4HotKeyProperty);
    }

    public static void SetDisableF4HotKey(DependencyObject obj, bool value)
    {
        obj.SetValue(DisableF4HotKeyProperty, value);
    }

    private static void OnDisableF4HotKeyChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var box = d as ComboBox;
        if (d == null) return;

        box.PreviewKeyDown -= OnComboBoxKeyDown;
        box.PreviewKeyDown += OnComboBoxKeyDown;
    }

    private static void OnComboBoxKeyDown(object _, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Key == System.Windows.Input.Key.F4)
        {
            e.Handled = true;
        }
    }
}
```

In your xaml file, add a namespace reference to the `ComboBoxHelper` class and set the attached property on your ComboBox:

```
 <ComboBox h:ComboBoxHelper.DisableF4HotKey="True" />
```

Answer (score 3):

use this

```
cboTest.PreviewKeyDown += (o,e) => {
    if (e.Key == Key.F4)
        e.Handled = true;
};
```

cboTest is your ComboBox Name

Comment: Don't forget to call `ProcessOrders()`

Comment: This behavior is only for stopping the ComboBox popup? Rest I think the questioner can handle!

Comment: I'm just sayin'.  I doubt that the F4 gets passed along to the next handler.

Comment: If I would have to call ProcessOrders() then that gets a bit messy (and if the Message has Handled=true then I would).  All my comboboxes would be calling ProcessOrders.  Hmmm I wonder if F5 has anything funky like this attached to it.

Comment: for purchaseorder you can handle the event at window level, Since PreviewKeyDown will BubbleDown, you can use KeyDown event which will bubble up to WIndow

Answer (score 2):

Use a custom combo box like this:

```
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Input;

namespace Your.Namespace
{
    public class CustomComboBox : ComboBox
    {
        protected override void OnKeyDown(KeyRoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Key != Windows.System.VirtualKey.F4)
            {
                base.OnKeyDown(e);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And then, in XAML, replace all the instances of the old combo box with the new custom combo box:

```
<CustomComboBox xmlns="using:Your.Namespace.Controls"
                ... />
```

Comment: can downvoter says what is my solution's defect?!! It works for me at a commercial program.

Answer (score 1):

How are you catching the F4 key?  If you use the keypreview, you can override it from bubbling down to the combo box:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.KeyPreview = true;
    this.KeyDown += new KeyEventHandler(Form1_KeyDown);
}

void Form1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.F4)
    {
        e.Handled = true;
        MessageBox.Show("F4 Pressed");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

By default the F4 key opens or closes the dropdown list of a combo box. This behavior can be altered to ignore the F4 key and open the list using the down arrow key instead. This is done by sending a [`CB_SETEXTENDEDUI`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775905.aspx) to the combo box providing a `TRUE` parameter. This is assuming that WPF does in fact use the native common controls internally.

Comment: What do you need more, @afruzan? How is this not the accepted solution? The described use case is literally one of the reasons why the ExtendedUI property exists in the first place. Thus, there's no reason at all to write multiple locs for workarounds for a thing you can do in one single line.